# reinstall ubuntu-desktop after accidently removed ibus

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, chroot

I accidentally removed ibus on my ubuntu 16 which is upgraded from 14.04 and suddenly I have unmet dependencies, broken packages, etc. I managed to chroot into the system using a live-cd-usb and mannually fixed a lot of dependencies by using aptitude install. But there are still dependencies I could not resolve manually, anyone has an idea what to do next?

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt install ubuntu-desktop
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     ubuntu-desktop : Depends: nautilus but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: nautilus-sendto but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: software-center but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: unity but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: bluez-alsa but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: brasero but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cheese but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: empathy but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: firefox but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: gnome-orca but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: nautilus-share but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: network-manager-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: network-manager-pptp-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: onboard but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: remmina but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: rhythmbox but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: shotwell but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: totem but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: totem-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: transmission-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: usb-creator-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: xul-ext-unity but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: xul-ext-webaccounts but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Info

```
root@ubuntu:/# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: that looks like a dependency chain ie one package brakes another which brakes another ....the trick is finding which one is first in the chain. `sudo apt-mark showhold`  will list held packages.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# sudo apt-mark showhold
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu

Comment: apt-mark showhold alone returns nothing

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# aptitude install xorg-input-abi-20
"xorg-input-abi-20" exists in the package database, but it is not a
real package and no package provides it.
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - openpty (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: try `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoremove` to clean up the package list

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# apt-get clean
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: now try `apt-get install -f`

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: I assume `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` still isn't working? maybe an unconfigured package-- this is going beyond my knowledge